# Want to show that sequences in little l 1 can be represented by orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that for a sequence $a=\{a_i\}^{\infty}_1 \in l^1$ I can write 
$$a= \sum ^\infty _{i=1} a_i e_i $$
For $\{e_i\}^\infty_1 \in l^1$ where the ith term is 1 and all else zero.

I know for $a\in span\{e_n\}$ (finite) I can write $$a= \sum ^n _{i=1} a_i e_i $$
How do I expand this to infinite dimensions?

Comment: Note that this basis is not really "orthonormal" in the traditional sense because $l^1$ does not admit an inner product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i = a$.

By definition, we have

$$\left\|a - \sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i\right\|_1 = \left\|(\underbrace{0, \ldots, 0}_{n}, a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}, \ldots)\right\|_1 = \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty |a_i| \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$
because $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|$ is a convergent series since $a \in \ell^1$.

Comment: Can you explain how it tend to zero?

Comment: @Seth You know that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|$ converges so
$$\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty |a_i| = \sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i| - \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i| \xrightarrow{n\to\infty}  \sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i| -  \sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i| =0$$

Answer (score 0):

$a\in\ell^1$ means that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_i|<\infty$. If the series converges then its tail goes to zero. Now, for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:

$||a-\sum_{i=1}^N a_ie_i||=||(0,...0,a_{N+1},a_{N+2},...)||=\sum_{i=N+1}^\infty |a_i|\to 0$

So by definition of convergence we have $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ie_i=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^N a_ie_i=a$.

Comment: This is a basic theorem about series. A series of numbers converges if and only if its tail goes to zero. To prove the direction that we need just write $\sum_{i=N+1}^\infty |a_i|=\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|-\sum_{i=1}^N |a_i|$. Now take $N\to\infty$ and use arithemetic of limits.